# How to make a USSD call on a iPhone from a button in a webpage?

Tags: iphone, html, web-applications, ussd

How to make a USSD call on a iPhone from a button in a webpage?

I have tried the urlencode `tel%3A*141%23` but that still does not work.

This is possible cause I can do a USSD call from my contacts application on Iphone?

Does anyone have a solution for this, I don't even need the USSD call to run 
in the background, just to make the USSD call.

I have read https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/PhoneLinks.html  about the special characters `*` and `#`

But how does my Contacts app do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contacts app has special privileges us mere mortal developers cannot possess.

The * and # characters are blocked from being used in tel: URLs.

Comment: Apple did this to prevent malicious apps from dialing "who knows what". Using these symbols, you can even reprogram telco services such as where voice mail goes and other nasty things.