# i tried to use openURL for make a ussd call in my native app in Xcode

Tags: ios

I tried to use openURL for make a **ussd** call in my native app in Xcode but after some search i find that **"*"** and **"#"** are not allowed in openURL string from **IOS 7** ...

Is there any solution to make ussd call in ios using objective c?

In android ussd calls works perfect

Comment: You are right but read answer here and comment also -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334145/how-to-make-a-ussd-call-on-a-iphone-from-a-button-in-a-webpage

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a USSD call on a iPhone from a button in a webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334145/how-to-make-a-ussd-call-on-a-iphone-from-a-button-in-a-webpage)